# Django Admin foreign key drop down from single SQL query

Tags: mysql, django-models, django-forms

Is there a simple way to get Django to populate the drop downs for a foreign key using a single SQL query?

Consider the following models;

```
class Site(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.code, self.name)

class Location(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name='Location Name')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.site, self.name)
```

Other models then include `models.ForeignKey(Location)` and for selecting them these render in the `admin.ModelAdmin` form as drop down lists.

Using the django-debug-toolbar I can see that I get the following query executed for every Location item with its `site_id` value when populating the drop downs;

```
SELECT 
  `myApp_site`.`id`, 
  `myApp_site`.`code`, 
  `myApp_site`.`name` 
FROM `myApp_site` 
WHERE `myApp_site`.`id` = 1
```

I can see that this is because I'm using `self.site` in `def __unicode__(self)` as I want to see the site with each location.

I tried using `list_select_related = True` in the `admin.ModelAdmin` but this is just for the related data on an instance and not for the possible values in the form.

Normally the whole foreign key drop down could be populated from a single query like;

```
SELECT 
  `myApp_location`.`id`, 
  `myApp_location`.`name`,
  `myApp_site`.`code`, 
  `myApp_site`.`name` 
FROM `myApp_site`
INNER JOIN `myApp_site` ON (`myApp_location`.`site_id` = `myApp_site`.`id`)
```

Can I force the Location model to use `select_related()` and eliminate the queries?

Is there a better way to include site with the location or reduce the number of queries Django is executing?

Is there a Django anti-pattern I've fallen into? I have several foreign key fields like this and I'm concerned about the number of queries increasing as the database fills up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the method formfield_for_foreignkey on the AdminClass, there you can overwrite the queryset of the ForeignKey. See example below

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'location':
        kwargs["queryset"] = Location.objects.select_related('site').all()
    return super(ModelWithLocationAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Excellent that's just reduced my query count from 193 to 125 and that was for just one db_field! Will also look at using `formfield_for_manytomany` and `formfield_for_choice_field`.